# Best approach for creating an image list

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-recyclerview, picasso

I need to create a Fragment with a list of images.

I did the following:

- RecyclerView;
- CardView with an ImageView;
- RecyclerView Adapter;

I have a list of urls with which I create an adapter. In the **onBindViewHolder** of the Adapter I use **Picasso** in order to load the images into the ImageView.

This approach works but I'm not sure it is the best. The images don't always have the right dimensions and I have a random bug, such as image appear and disappear during the scrolling.

What do you suggest?

EDIT:

**XML Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:id="@+id/card_view"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_margin="15dp"
 card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

 <ImageView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:scaleType="fitCenter"
     android:id="@+id/thumbnail"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your approach,the image size is due to your cardview layout (the xml file).
And also what kind of bug do you encounter,please give more details ?

Comment: @Boukharist watch for my edit please.

Comment: try android:scaleType="fitXY".
And if you want to scale image before loading it try this code
 `Picasso
    .with(context)
    .load(link)
    .resize(6000, 2000)
    .into(imageViewResize);`

See here for further information : [picasso image resizing](https://futurestud.io/blog/picasso-image-resizing-scaling-and-fit)

Answer (score 0):

I used the following approach and it works well for me.

> The images don't always have the right dimensions

My `ImageView`

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_college_news"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_90"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_90"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_default_image" />
```

And display the image using [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) with the following setting:

```
DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY_STRETCHED)
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisk(true)
            .considerExifParams(true)
            .build();
```

Hope it helps.